# I cannot get any browser to open up with selenium using Eclipse (neon) , testNG

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

I've been using Eclipse to automate my tests for several months. One day I come in to run a test that worked the day before and the Browser (Firefox) is blank. Here is the first part of the error:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   Default","description":"The default
>   theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla
>   Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Mozilla
>   Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1499203612256,"updateDate":1499203612256,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":19587,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"52.2.1","maxVersion":"52.2.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false}

So naturally I throw that into google and look up the error and I see a lot of references to "Geckodriver." Something about if you have FF 47 or later, you need to use this geckodriver. Now my company pushes updates every couple of weeks, so it makes sense that they would upgrade Firefox. My current version is 52, sop I go to Github and download Geckopdriver and point to it like so:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "*the path to it on my machine*");`

Upon trying again I'm still get a blank screen. Following is the error message:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   Default","description":"The default
>   theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla
>   Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Mozilla
>   Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1499203612256,"updateDate":1499203612256,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":19587,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"52.2.1","maxVersion":"52.2.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false}

I'm not able to find any relevant reference that can help with my specific specs (Win 7, FF 52, Eclipse Neon, TestNG)

Since I knew that we create object of `chromedriver` to test on `GoogleChrome`, I prefered `FireFox`. But as I relized problem with `FireFox`, I thought to try the script on `Chrome`.

So I changed the browser to this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "*path*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And this time Chrome opened, with only "data;" in the URL. Here was the error message:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.53.0',
>   revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'

I can't seem to get any browser to work, and I have been unproductive, trying to fix this for 3 days. I tried to upgrade the version of selenium, but that required updated jar files, which required me to update my version of chrome to 58, which I cannot due to system policy (updates are disabled by your administrator.) Other solutions were focused on various configurations that I do not have, like Ubuntu and Opera and whatever else.

Can somebody help me to get this working again on ONE browser so I can get back to work? Thank you for any help you can give me!

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things.

Which operating system are you using **32-bit** or **64-bit**?

1. make sure the driver (gecko or chrome any other) you have downloaded is as per your operating system.
2. Try to run them from command line to see what's happening.
3. if you are using linux, make sure driver has proper permission

Comment: I am using a 64-bit system with a 64-bit geckodriver. When you say run them from the command line, do you mean the automations themselves?

Comment: i mean opem `CMD` and try to run executable, see if you are getting any error.

Comment: try to run geckodriver.exe by itself? Here's something I just realized - my firefox is 32-bit version. Would that make a difference?

Comment: I think yes, try 32-bit version of gecko driver and try changing firefox to 64-bit

Comment: Also when I ran geckodriver.exe from the command line it said it was listening.

Comment: I can't change firefox, it is updated by administrator, but I will try the 32 bit geckodriver.

Comment: how about this `https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads` for chrome.

Comment: Believe it or not, when you sent me to that site I looked for the version of chromedriver that predates my version of chrome. I threw it in the proper directory.... AND IT WORKS! Thank you SO MUCH!!

Comment: because for chromedriver they don't have spearate version for 64-bit or 32-bit, one works for all.

Answer (score 1):

1- download latest firefox or chrome driver
2- please update your selenium server dependency, it seems your selenium stand-alone.jar is not compatible with your browser version.
download selenium server latest jar from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
or add below maven dependency in your  POM

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

please let me know if it solve your issue : )

Comment: actually, that was one of the things that caused the problem initially. I don't have control over browser updates here at work. The 3.4.0 was not compatible with chrome 54, I needed 58 or later and was unable to upgrade. But it is working now, and I thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For Google Chrome, you may try this code:

```
public class FSO_CheckCase {
    WebDriver driver;
@BeforeTest     
public void setup ()
{          
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "*path*\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");  
options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);               
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
} 

@Test(priority = 0)     
public void Google () throws InterruptedException    
{
driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

If this works, same code can be used for `FireFox`. Be careful while you mention path where you have saved `chromedriver.exe` and `Geckodriver.exe`. Let me know if it still creates problem for you.

Comment: Hi Sanchit - I was able to fix it without that code, but I will definitely use it if it stops working again - thanks!

Comment: @Munchy: Noted. My best wishes to you :-)